# Adapter pattern in C++ via Inheritance and Composition

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns

Any suggestions on how the implementation of the C++ Adapter pattern could be improved here? Implemented via:

1. Composition
2. Inheritance

What needed to be adapted was the `OptionLegacy` class which returns implied volatility of the option but the client needs the dollar price so a simple conversion was included.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// Return price of option by volatility
// Adaptee - old legacy type option objects
class OptionLegacy
{
protected:
    float volatilityPrc;
    double spotPrice;
    int expiryDays;

public:
    OptionLegacy(float v, double s, int t) :
        volatilityPrc(v), spotPrice(s), expiryDays(t) {}

    float GetVol() const {
        return volatilityPrc;
    }
    double GetSpot() const {
        return spotPrice;
    }
    int GetTau() const {
        return expiryDays;
    }
};


// Return price of option in dollars. Current interface that client uses
class OptionPriceDollars
{
protected:
    float vol;
    double spot;
    double tau;

public:
    OptionPriceDollars() = default;
    OptionPriceDollars(float v, double s, double t) :
        vol(v), spot(s), tau(t) {}

    virtual float GetPrice() {
        return 0.4 * spot * vol * sqrt(tau);
    }
};

// via composition
class Adapter
{
    OptionLegacy adaptee;

public:
    Adapter(const OptionLegacy & o):  adaptee(o) {}

    float GetPrice() {
        return 0.4 * adaptee.GetSpot() * adaptee.GetVol() / 100 * sqrt(adaptee.GetTau()/365);
    }
};

// via inheritance
class AdapterInheritance : public OptionPriceDollars, private OptionLegacy
{

public:
    AdapterInheritance(const OptionLegacy & o) : OptionLegacy(o.GetVol(), o.GetSpot(), o.GetTau()) {};

    float GetPrice() override {
        return 0.4 * spotPrice * volatilityPrc / 100 * expiryDays / 365;
    }

};


int main()
{
    OptionPriceDollars od(0.14, 100, 1);
    std::cout << "The price of the option is " << od.GetPrice() << std::endl;

    OptionLegacy op(14, 100, 365);
    Adapter a(op);
    std::cout << "The price of the old style option is (composition) " << a.GetPrice() << std::endl;

    AdapterInheritance b(op);
    std::cout << "The price of the old style option is (inheritance) " << b.GetPrice() << std::endl;

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Incorrect use of inheritance

There is a problem with `class AdapterInheritance`. It contains both the member variables of `OptionLegacy` and of `OptionPriceDollars`. But only one set of variables is desired; those of `OptionLegacy`. You should not inherit from the concrete `OptionPriceDollars` class. If anything, you should only inherit from an "interface", however C++ does not have interface classes like some other programming languages. You could use pure virtual functions to create an [abstract base class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), but that's not exactly the same. So I recommend you just write:

```
class AdapterInheritance : private OptionLegacy
{
public:
    AdapterInheritance(const OptionLegacy & o) : OptionLegacy(o.GetVol(), o.GetSpot(), o.GetTau()) {};

    float GetPrice() {
        return 0.4 * spotPrice * volatilityPrc / 100 * expiryDays / 365;
    }
};
```

Or if you need to use a base class, create an abstract one:

```
class OptionPrice {
public:
    virtual float GetPrice() = 0;
};
```

And have both `AdapterInheritance` and `OptionPriceDollars` publicly inherit from that.

## Other ways to create adaptable interfaces

C++ is a multi-paradigm language. You don't have to put everything into classes. You could create a freestanding function `GetPrice()` that takes a reference to any object, and calls the member function `GetPrice()`:

```
template<typename T>
float GetPrice(T& o) {
    return o.GetPrice();
}
```

That would then work on `OptionPriceDollars` as well as your adapters. To make it also work with `OptionLegacy`, you can provide an overload of `GetPrice()`:

```
float GetPrice(OptionLegacy& adaptee) {
    return 0.4 * adaptee.GetSpot() * adaptee.GetVol() / 100 * sqrt(adaptee.GetTau()/365);
}
```

That way, in `main()` you can write:

```
std::cout << "The price of the option is " << GetPrice(od) << '\n';
std::cout << "The price of the old style option is " << GetPrice(op) << '\n';
```

## Be consistent

I see different variable names for exactly the same thing, like `volatilityPrc`, `vol` and `v`. I see both `float` and `double` being used, if the result of `GetPrice()` is going to be a `float`, why use `double`s? Why does `OptionPriceDollars` have a default constructor but the other classes don't?

## Prefer `\n` over `std::endl`

Prefer using ['\n' instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not necessary and might impact performance.

## Improve the constructor of `AdapterInheritance`

You can make use of the fact that `OptionLegacy` has an implicit copy constructor, and simplify the constructor of `AdapterInheritance` like so:

```
AdapterInheritance(const OptionLegacy & o) : OptionLegacy(o) {}
```

That's actually very much what you did in `Adapter`. Another way to implement the constructor is to have it accept any set of arguments, and pass them on to the constructor of `OptionLegacy`:

```
template<typename... Args>
AdapterInheritance(Args&&... args): OptionLegacy(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

Which might look weird if you have never used [templates parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [perfect forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) before, but this is a standard way to do this. The advantage is that you only have to write this one constructor, and it will cover all the possible constructors `OptionLegacy` has, including the implicit copy and move constructors. Another advantage of this is that you no longer have to create an `OptionLegacy` first, you can now just write:

```
AdapterInheritance b(14, 100, 365);
```